# gRPC Connection Issue in Android Emulator: "Error connecting: Connection shutting down."

Tags: android, flutter, dart, grpc, riverpod

When attempting to establish a gRPC connection from the Android emulator, the error "Error connecting: Connection shutting down." occurs.

Problematic code:

```
import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import '/api/v1/user/Auth.pbgrpc.dart';

final clientProvider = Provider.autoDispose<ClientChannel>((ref) {
  const host = '10.0.2.2';
  const port = 3000;
  final channel = ClientChannel(
    host,
    port: port,
    options: const ChannelOptions(
      credentials: host == '10.0.2.2'
          ? ChannelCredentials.insecure()
          : ChannelCredentials.secure(),
    ),
  );
  ref.onDispose(() {
    channel.shutdown();
  });
  return channel;
});

final tokenProvider = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => null);
final refreshTokenProvider = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => null);

CallOptions _callOptionsWithToken(Ref ref) {
  final token = ref.watch(tokenProvider);
  final refreshToken = ref.watch(refreshTokenProvider);
  final metadata = token != null && refreshToken != null
      ? <String, String>{
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          'X-Refresh-Token': refreshToken
        }
      : <String, String>{};
  return CallOptions(metadata: metadata);
}

final authControllerProvider =
    Provider.autoDispose<AuthControllerClient>((ref) {
  final channel = ref.watch(clientProvider);
  return AuthControllerClient(channel, options: _callOptionsWithToken(ref));
});
```

Function being called:

```dart
dartCopy code
Future<void> signIn(WidgetRef ref, String email, String password) async {
    final authController = ref.read(authControllerProvider);

    try {
      final response = await authController.signIn(
        UserAuthRequest(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        ),
      );
      print(response);

      if (response.accessToken != "") {
        ref
            .read(tokenProvider.notifier)
            .update((state) => response.accessToken);
      }
      if (response.refreshToken != "") {
        ref
            .read(refreshTokenProvider.notifier)
            .update((state) => response.refreshToken);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Login failed: $e");
    }
  }
```

Contents of Auth.proto:

```dart
dartCopy code
syntax = "proto3";

package server.admin;
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

message AdminAuthRequest {
  string email = 1;
  string password = 2;
}
message AdminRefreshTokenRequest {
    string accessToken = 1;
    string refreshToken= 2;
}

message AdminAuthResponse {
    string accessToken = 1;
    int64 expiresIn = 2;
    string refreshToken= 3;
}
message AdminRegisterRequest {
  string Name = 1;
  string Mail = 2;
  string BelongStoreID = 4;
}

message ResetPasswordRequest{
  string email = 1;
}

message UpdatePasswordRequest{
  string password = 1;
}

message UpdateEmailRequest{
  string email = 1;
}

service AuthController {
  rpc Register(AdminRegisterRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
  rpc SignUp(AdminAuthRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
  rpc SignOut(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
  rpc Refresh(AdminRefreshTokenRequest) returns (AdminAuthResponse) {}
  rpc SignIn(AdminAuthRequest) returns (AdminAuthResponse) {}
  rpc ResetPasswordMail(ResetPasswordRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
  rpc UpdatePassword(UpdatePasswordRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
  rpc UpdateEmail(UpdateEmailRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}
```

Communication with external sources, such as REST API and Firebase, works fine within the app.

Directly connecting to the gRPC server using grpcurl without using this app was successful.

I tried three different addresses: localhost, 10.0.2.2, and an external URL (GCP), but the results were the same.

Error displayed in the console:

```
Login failed: gRPC Error (code: 14, codeName: UNAVAILABLE, message: Error connecting: Connection shutting down., details: null, rawResponse: null, trailers: {})
```

```
Flutter 3.16.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 9e1c857886 (3 weeks ago) • 2023-11-30 11:51:18 -0600
Engine • revision cf7a9d0800
Tools • Dart 3.2.2 • DevTools 2.28.3
```

Comment: It could be how you ran your grpc server. If you bind it to localhost or 127.0.0.1 it will be accessible with grpcurl from your machine but it won't be accessible from the emulator. Make sure you bind to 0.0.0.0 to accept any address.